actions$ not injected in constructor of effect
I use NGRX 18 and Angular 18, I am trying to inject actions$ into my effect via constructor, but this doesn't work
import { inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { actionsList } from "./students.actions";
import { catchError, exhaustMap, map, of } from "rxjs";
import { StudentsRecordsService } from "../services/students-records.service";

@Injectable()
export class StudentsRecordsEffects {
  // actions$ = inject(Actions);
  // studentsRecordsService = inject(StudentsRecordsService);

  loadStudentsRecords$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actionsList.callStudentsRecordsApi),
    exhaustMap(() => this.studentsRecordsService.getStudentsRecords().pipe(
      map(studentsRecords => {
        console.log('API Response:', studentsRecords); // Debug API Response
        return { type: actionsList.callStudentsRecordsApiSuccess, payload: studentsRecords }
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching students records:', error); // Debug Error
        return of({ type: '[Students API] Students Loaded Error' });
      }),
    ))
  ));

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private studentsRecordsService: StudentsRecordsService
  ) {}
}

My error in console:
main.ts:6 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
    at students.effects.ts:12:59
    at <instance_members_initializer> (students.effects.ts:12:26)
    at new _StudentsRecordsEffects (students.effects.ts:26:3)
    at Object.StudentsRecordsEffects_Factory [as factory] (students.effects.ts:31:3)

If I try to inject actions$ with the inject() method instead, everything works correctly.
What's wrong?
